# How to clear selected user input components in JFrame after data added to database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, user-input

I am doing a form where users can input data to be added to the database. I would like to reset the form upon successful submission of data for the user to continue adding different sets of data.

I have a reference number field where the values would be inputted automatically, so I do not want to clear that field. Also, the reference number increases by 1 automatically.

I would like to clear all text fields except for the reference number's text field, and at the same time, increment the reference number by 1. Currently, I can only do this by returning to my main page, then clicking on Add Data again.

Is there any code for this without the need to return to the main page?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, because `textField.setText("");` should work fine...

Answer (score 2):

Because the user should wait for successful submission, initiate the transaction in the context of a [modal dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). Because the transaction may take some time, or fail altogether, submit the transaction using a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513). If successful, you can reset the relevant fields in your implementation of `done()`; if not, you can offer to cancel or retry the transaction.