# Border layout doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, jpanel

I would like to achieve the below layout.

[image]

There are 6 panels. The 4 buttons at the top are one panel, and the 3 buttons at the right side of the image are also in one panel. Apart from those two there are 4 other panels as indicated by the borders. I tried the below code but displays everything in a scattered way.

```
mainPanel.add(topToolBarPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
mainPanel.add(lefsideToolBarPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
mainPanel.add(descriptionPanel,BorderLayout.LEFT);
mainPanel.add(mapPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(propertiesPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
mainPanel.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

How can I achieve the design as shown in the image? I need all the panels to be arranged inside that mainPanel. I cannot use null layout though. Please advice.

After trashgod's answer :

```
    JPanel gridPanel =  new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    gridPanel.add(jInternalFrame1);
    gridPanel.add(descriptionPanel);
    mainPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    mainPanel.add(topToolBarPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    mainPanel.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    mainPanel.add(mapPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(PropertiesPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

What I get :

[image]

Comment: You can put 2 things LEFT(EAST) whatever wrap the map panel around another panel where u put the description panel left or use a gridpane that fills the whole frame

Comment: when I put two things left, it puts them on another. Grid pane doesn't arrange it this way as well

Comment: u don't get it ...

Comment: Can you give me an answer in code? Would appreciate it much :)

Comment: Here is an image for you
https://i.gyazo.com/3f0c82111277b5f459b5a425999873e4.png
And yes, i made it with paint thats why it is ugly

Comment: I dont understand how to do that with a grid layout! row i doesnt have 4 columns! can you show some example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `lefsideToolBarPanel` and `descriptionPanel` to a panel having `GridLayout`; add the new panel to the `BorderLayout`.

```
Panel p  new Panel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
p.add(lefsideToolBarPanel);
p.add(descriptionPanel);
//mainPanel.add(lefsideToolBarPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
//mainPanel.add(descriptionPanel, BorderLayout.LEFT);
mainPanel.add(p, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

There is no `BorderLayout.LEFT`. See also [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Addendum: Your updated question shows elements of `topToolBarPanel`, which should be added to `PAGE_START`, rather than `LINE_START`.

```
//mainPanel.add(topToolBarPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
mainPanel.add(topToolBarPanel,BorderLayout. PAGE_START);
```

[image]

> The width of the `propertiesPanel` and height of the `tablePanel` need to be increased. I used `setSize()`…

For the `propertiesPanel`, you can override `getPreferredSize()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). For the `tablePanel`, override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to customize the size of the table's enclosing `JScrollPane`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Comment: It doesn't work as well. I edited the question with the code I tried as you suggested and the output i got :(

Comment: i've edited the question again. This time its close. But still not the exactly intended design. :(

Comment: `GridLayout(3, 0)` means "_three_ rows and as many columns as necessary;" `GridLayout(1, 0)` means "_one_ row and as many columns as necessary." See [nested layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) for more.

Comment: I edited the question again with the image I get. Now the placement is accurate. But the width of the properties panel and height of the tablePanel needs to be increased. I used setSize but it doesn't have any effect. Is it not possible to increase the height and width inside the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a **JLabel** as your "layout" to use exact positioning of yout objects with setBounds(x, y, width, height). It would look similar to this :

```
JButton button = new JButton("Text or Image");
JLabel backgr = new JLabel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel as Layout");

button.setBounds(100, 200, 340, 40);

backgr.add(button);

frame.add(backgr);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLocation(40, 40);
frame.validate();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I know that this is just a quick example for you, but I think it should do for explanation... so just add everything on the **backgr** JLabeland your good to go. [Quick and dirty example but the a way to go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK0QS.png).

Comment: Please don't promote null layouts.