# how to get data from DataBase and put them in JTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using perfectly JTableModel thanks to the document our friends from stackoverflow suggested them to  me but i have a litlle problem . this how a lot of documents initalize the data

```
Object[][] data = {
{"Kathy", "Smith",
 "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
```

But in my case the date is on the DataBase and i'm using busines delegate so i want to get the information from the DataBase knowing that i have a method who get all the Responsable (in my exemple) the methode name is

```
DoReadAllResponsable()
```

Comment: `this how a lot of documents initalize the data` -  there are many examples in the forum that show how to load data from a database into a JTable. You can start by looking at the topic found under the `Related` heading on the right side of this page.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Comment: @camickr is erached but i didn't found what i want related with my exemple