# Pre-existing jTable very slow - even on few records

Tags: java, sql, performance, jtable

Seeking help again...

I  have a query that I run, when I run it in Netbeans it's very fast (less than a second) and about a second to display the info. When I run the same query and populate a JTable (defined at design time, not runtime), it is very slow.

DB has about 600 records - delay of 20 seconds
Limit to 10 - delay of about 10 seconds
Limit to 1 - delay of about 3 seconds

Is there a way to make the Tablemodel "quicker"?

I have contemplated paging, but even a delay of 10 seconds for about 10 records is not great - something must be inherently wrong with my code (sorry, complete Java Noob).

Below is my code:

```
String SQL = "SELECT RecTable.ipkRecNo, RecTable.RecName order by ipkRecNo";

DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );

int i = 0; 
String PreviousKey = "";
while ( rs.next( ) ) {
i++;
String MyRecNum = "";
String MyRecName = "";

if (rs.getString(1).trim() == PreviousKey.trim() ) {
} else {

MyRecNum = rs.getString(1);
MyRecName = rs.getString(1);

defaultModel.addRow(new Object[]{MyRecNum,MyRecName}); //1307
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*AbstractTableModel GUI display issue*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34738845/230513).

Comment: Query the database in the background, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for [addRow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method states:

> Inserts a row at row in the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. **Notification of the row being added will be generated.**

So, 1307 times event is generated. and that makes your program slow.