# How to get the values from database?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, classnotfoundexception

I have tried to get the values from DB using Java. I need to get the student name and his father name which already saved in the DB when entering his roll number.

I tried the below code and I am getting an error. (**Edit** error after stack trace printed.)

```
ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Suggest the solution or issues.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test1  {

   JFrame f;
   JLabel l1,l2;
   JTextField f1;
   JButton b1;
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    /**
     * Creates new form Register
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Test1 r=new Test1();
        r.frame();
        r.connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/servicename","username","password");
            st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            String str = "select student_name,father_name from student_db where roll_no='&roll_no'";
            st.executeUpdate(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }


    }

    public void frame() 
    {
     f=new JFrame ("studentrecord");
     f1=new JTextField(10);
     b1=new JButton("submit");
     l1=new JLabel("student_name");
     l2=new JLabel("father_name");

     f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     f.add(l1);
     f.add(f1);
     f.add(l2);
     f.add(b1);
     f.setVisible(true);
     f.pack();
     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String student_name=l1.getText();
            String father_name=l2.getText();
            String roll_no=f1.getText();
            System.out.println(student_name);
            System.out.println(father_name);
            System.out.println(roll_no);

            connect();
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Also the student name and father name label values should display under the roll number  but its displayed next to the submit button.is there any other better layout there to display like that?

Comment: 1) *"i am not getting any error. .. `} catch (Exception ex) {
        }`"* You won't have any idea about errors when writing code like that.  Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) Is the problem getting the data, or displaying it? *"Also the student name and father name label values should display.."* Test them separately in order to narrow the problem down. SO is not a help desk, or a tutoring service. It is a Q&A site.

Comment: yes, the problem is displaying the data

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Comment: *"the problem is displaying the data"* Factor out the database by hard coding some `String` data in the code itself. Populate the display with that data when the user actions a button.

Comment: actually i took the code from online for insert the values in db then converted the query for view the values in db. but i have doubt the code which written is correct to display the data.

Comment: yeah hardcode will be helpful only

Comment: Now i have updated the above code and added the print statement,when executing the code it prints what the value in the str but the System.out.println(student_name); prints the same variable name student_name only , i am not getting any values from student_name table for that roll no.similar to the father name and rollno too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the code below will do the read query. But for God's sake, read the documentation before trying to write something.

```
public String studentName(String rollNo) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    String names = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servicename","username","password");
        stm = con.prepareStatement("select student_name,father_name from student_db where roll_no=?");
        stm.setString(1,  rollNo);
        rst = stm.executeQuery();
        if (rst.next())
            names = rst.getString(1)+","+rst.getString(2);
        rst.close();
        rst = null;
        stm.close();
        stm=null;
        con.close();
        con = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (rst!=null) rst.close();
        if (stm!=null) stm.close();
        if (con!=null) con.close();
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: yeah sure thanks, i tried the printStackTrace its giving the below error 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` is because the DB driver is not on the run-time class-path of the application.

Comment: yes @AndrewThompson you are correct i have included the ojdbc14 jar then its connected i think.

Comment: i am struggling in the view part in swing from the db

Answer (score 0):

stm = con.prepareStatement("select student_name,father_name from student_db where roll_no=?");
stm.setString(1,  rollNo);
rst = stm.executeQuery();

This definitely works.